# Auto-resize jFrame properly in netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I have made a `JFrame` and I defined a background image using a `JLabel`. But, as soon as I enlarge the `JFrame` everything gets dislocated. How can I build my `JFrame` so it can be resizable?

```
public class First extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form First
     */
    public First() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        t1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t2 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("WELCOME");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe Script", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("LOGIN");
        jButton1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(280, 310, 140, 30));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Viner Hand ITC", 3, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Administrator of Library System");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 30, 614, -1));

        t1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 3, 20)); // NOI18N
        t1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        t1.setOpaque(false);
        t1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(t1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 200, 180, 30));

        t2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        t2.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        t2.setOpaque(false);
        getContentPane().add(t2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 250, 180, 30));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe Script", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Username     -");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 200, 200, 30));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe Script", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Password     -");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 250, 230, 30));

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe Script", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Forgot Password ??");
        jButton2.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        jButton2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 410, 250, 40));

        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/librarymanagementsystem/library_book.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-10, -10, 880, 500));

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void t1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try
        {
            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");  
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "parin");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            String username="";
            String password="";

            String query="Select * from Liblogin;";
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);



            while(rs.next())
            {
                username=rs.getString("username");
                password=rs.getString("password");
            }


            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();


            String enteredUsername=t1.getText().toString();
            String enteredPassword = new String(t2.getText());
            if(enteredUsername.contentEquals(username)&&enteredPassword.contentEquals(password))
            {
                Homepage a=new Homepage();
                a.setVisible(true); 
                this.dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"INVALID USER");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR IN CORRECTION");
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
        Security a=new Security();
        a.setVisible(true);

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(First.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(First.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(First.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(First.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new First().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField t2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: No one? I am using net beans.

Comment: I suggest you read some material on `LayoutManager`, and how they can be used to manage the visible space in your container.

Comment: I have found that grid bag layout is appropriate.But,still ain't able to resize.

Comment: Then post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How are we suppose to provide any kind of meaningful,answer without seeing what it is you have tried. Provide better context in form of an example so we can better understand your problem. Also note, JLabel won't rescale the image

Comment: What is the best way to provide a background image? if not using a label then?

Comment: A quick check at your questions history shows that you are posting low quality questions. Please read the information on SSCCE (in my previous comment), and this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your questions. As they stands, they do not meet the quality requirements on SO. I also suggest you remain polite and respectful, and use the comments of other SO members to improve your questions, not as a personal offense.

Comment: It looks like the Netbeans' GUI editor is getting in your way; why not try a few examples from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridBagLayout` as your layout manager and take time to look at the `preferredSize`, `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` properties of components.You can also use [Box.Filler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.Filler.html) class to create Invisible components and add them between the components in your `JPanel` when the window is resized.I can't help you any further since I don't know what do you exactly want the components to behave like.I recommend you reading the book [Swing](http://www.manning.com/robinson2/) , chapter 4 is for you